# How to check privilege based on string instead of table row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web app the admin can assign a web page to a specific user, therefore that user can only access that specific page.

So to give an idea of how this works:

1. in my database I have a table with the web pages in, Webpage1.aspx, Webpage2.aspx etc.
2. The admin can create an user assign Webpage1.aspx to that user
3. Then when that user logs in they can only see the link to their page (all other links are hidden)

This is now the problem I have:

1. This works on a `DataTable` row number so when adding a new web form it re-arranges the `DataTable` row numbers which then when the user logs in again they can see all other links cause the table numbers have changed.

So to give a visual idea:

```
if (Session["Privilege"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtPrivilege = (DataTable)Session["Privilege"];

            /* Dashboard */
            if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[1]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[1]["FormName"].ToString() == "dashboard.aspx")
                lnkDashboard.Visible = false;

            /* Settings */
            if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[2]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[2]["FormName"].ToString() == "general.aspx")
                lnkSettings.Visible = false;

            /* Web Pages */
            if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[0]["Read"].ToString()) == false)
                lnkWebpages.Visible = false;
            else
            {
                if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[0]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[0]["FormName"].ToString() == "Webpage1.aspx")
                    lnkWebpage1.Visible = false;
            }
```

So it reads by row number so when you add another page it messes up the row number and the 1st users saved in the database then gets the wrong link assigned to their privilege, because it moved the row number to 1 or 2 depending on how many web forms have been added.

So my question is, how can I make it so that it reads the string instead of the row number?  So for example

```
  if (Session["Privilege"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtPrivilege = (DataTable)Session["Privilege"];

            /* Web Pages */
            if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[0]["Read"].ToString()) == false)
                lnkWebpages.Visible = false;
            else
            {
                if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[**Webpage1.aspx**]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[0]["FormName"].ToString() == "Webpage1.aspx")
                    lnkWebpage1.Visible = false;
            }
```

Is this possible and if so how can I achieve my goal?

Please let me know if you need more info or I haven't explained properly :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq to achieve this.
Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs page.

Then add below line to generate IEnumerable(Array) of all rows inside dtPrivilege DataTable,

```
DataRow[] allRows = dtPrivilege.Select();
```

And finally, add if blocks like below for all your webpages.

```
if (allRows.Any(x => x["FormName"].ToString() == "Webpage1.aspx" &&  
                     x["Read"].ToString().ToLower() == "false"))
{
    lnkWebpage1.Visible = false;
}
```

**What above if block says:**
It checks if there exists **Any** row in **allRows**, which has **FormName** = "Webpage1.aspx" and **Read** = "false". And if it exist, just set **lnkWebpage1.Visible** = false

Comment: Hi Great stuff!! Thanks,  the only problem now is that it is not hiding the links the user hasn't got access to?

Comment: did you add if block for all your webPages? And what is default value for `lnkWebpage.Visible`?